# Subspace of regular countably compact $X$ consisting of all points at which $X$ is weakly countably tight is $G_\delta$

Tags: general-topology

[image]

In the last two lines, why did the author say $X_t$ is a $G_\delta$-subset of $X$? What's his intention?

Comment: What is meant by a $k$-countable base?  (Also, what is the source of this proof?)

Comment: @Arthur: Took a while, but I found it: Arhangel’skiǐ, Just, Rezniczenko, & Szeptycki, *Sharp bases and weakly uniform bases versus point-countable bases*, Topology and its Applications, Volume 100, issue 1 (January 3, 2000), p. 39-46. $\mathscr{U}$ is $k$-countable (for some $k\in\Bbb Z^+$) if every $k$-point set is contained in at most countably many members of $\mathscr{U}$. $X$ is weakly countably tight if each $x\in X$ is in the closure of some countable subset of $X\setminus\{x\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $\mathscr{B}_0=\{B\in\mathscr{B}:B\cap X_t\ne\varnothing\}$ is countable, since the base $\mathscr{B}$ is point-countable at each point of $X_t$ and $X_t$ is separable. Let $U$ be any open nbhd of $X_t$; for each $x\in X_t$ there is a $B_x\in\mathscr{B}_0$ such that $x\in B_x\subseteq U$. $X_t$ is compact, so there is a finite $F(U)\subseteq X_t$ such that $X_t\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in F(U)}B_x\subseteq U$. Then

$$\mathscr{G}=\left\{\bigcup_{x\in F(U)}B_x:U\text{ is an open nbhd of }X_t\right\}$$

is a countable family of open sets whose intersection is $X_t$:

- $\mathscr{G}$ is countable, since $\mathscr{B}_0$ has only countably many finite subsets, and every $G\in\mathscr{G}$ is a union of finitely many members of $\mathscr{B}_0$.
- Clearly $X_t\subseteq\bigcap\mathscr{G}$.
- If $x\in X\setminus X_t$, then $X\setminus\{x\}$ is an open nbhd of $X_t$, so $X_t\subseteq G\subseteq X\setminus\{x\}$ for some $G\in\mathscr{G}$.

For each $G\in\mathscr{G}$ let $\mathscr{B}_G=\big\{\{x\}:x\in X\setminus G\big\}$; then $\mathscr{B}_G$ is discrete in $X$. Clearly $\{B\}$ is a discrete collection for each $B\in\mathscr{B}_0$. Thus, the base $\mathscr{B}_0\cup\big\{\{x\}:x\in X\setminus X_t\big\}$ is $\sigma$-discrete: the countably many discrete subcollections are the singletons $\{B\}$ for $B\in\mathscr{B}_0$ and the families $\mathscr{B}_G$ for $G\in\mathscr{G}$. We need to know that $X_t$ is a $G_\delta$-set in $X$ in order to break up $\big\{\{x\}:x\in X\setminus X_t\big\}$ into countably many discrete subcollections.

Comment: Thanks Brain. What is meaning of $\{B\}$?

Comment: @Simple: $\{B\}$ is the set whose only member is $B$; I seem to have got an extra pair of braces there, which I’ve now removed.

Comment: I see. Thaks again:)

Comment: @Simple: You’re welcome!